# Resultados em iframe

Tags: html, django, iframe

Quero mostrar os resultados da variavel "data numa iframe chamada "final.html". quando executo o codigo na iframe entra num loop que resulta um erro. ai tem o codigo que desenvolvi

views.py

```
def notification_html(request):
    data = _notification(request, url)
    render(request, 'notification_result.html', {'notifications': data})
    return render(request,'final.html')
```

notification_result.html

```
<body>
    {% if notifications %}
        <ul>
           {% for n in notifications %}
                <li style="background-color:{{ n.notification_type.color }}"><b>{{ n.title }}</b> - {{ n.description }} </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No notifications.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </body>
```

final.html

```
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height=auto style="border: none" src="notification_result.html" name="iframe_notification"></iframe>
Hi and welcome this page contains the iframe
</body>
```

O codigo funciona perfeitamente sem a iframe

Comment: Qual o numero de notifications em {% for n in notifications %}?

Comment: Ja consegui resolver o problema criando um metodo que chama o iframe e o iframe chama o metodo notification_html.

Comment: Pnelson, se você resolveu o problema, por favor coloque a solução como resposta para que outros usuários a encontrem se chegarem a essa pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido:
A soluçao foi criar um metodo que chama o iframe e o iframe chama o metodo notification_htmlv2.

```
def notification_html(request):
    url = request.META["QUERY_STRING"]
    return render(request, 'TTS Corporate.html', {"notes": '/notification_htmlv2/?' + url})


def notification_htmlv2(request):
    url = request.META["QUERY_STRING"]
    urls = decode(url)
    data = _notification(request, urls)
    return render(request, 'notification_result.html', {'notifications': data})
```

final.html

```
<iframe width="100%" src="{{ notes }}">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```